# How to create threads in leveling feet

Tags: oven, level, footings

Due to uneven floor, part of the oven does not stay parallel to the counter. I tried to tighten up the foot of the oven but it still does not fix the problem.

This is how the foot looks like:

[image]

Is there a way i can create couple of more threads in the foot to make it work?

Comment: My Precious, it could be done, but it will take a lot of time and care. The potential of screwing it up will still be plenty high. *gollum!!*

Answer (score 3):

Your cheapest and easiest option is a spacer under the foot. A small piece of plywood or a couple of wood shims will do the trick. Both will be available at a home improvement center or lumber supplier.

Answer (score 3):

Option #2:

Unscrew the other three feet a little bit.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: That would raise up the oven above the counter surface.

Comment: Option #3 would be to remove the foot entirely and replace it with a shim. You could also stick one of the large felt furniture pads under it so it doesn't scrape on the floor.